# Web application unix pager alike to view or edit internet document a.k.a. force mime content type proxy

Tags: gratis, web-apps

It's a little like two questions, but I think they are very related.

The first thing I want is an web application that accepts a URL, downloads that resource, and forwards the data as a `text/plain` mime content type to the client.

The usage scenario I am currently in is there is a resource located at `https://1.2.3.4/1.txt` , the host (falsely) serves this as *application/octet-stream* or some other binary type. I want to send this link to a friend for inspecting in a web browser instead of saving to the disk. I am aware [there are client side solutions for a browser software to override server supplied mime content type on demand](https://superuser.com/questions/420795/firefox-does-not-render-html-if-content-type-http-header-is-missing) but it is not feasible for *every* receipt of that link to have such measures deployed. So instead, I want a web application interfaced like `https://5.6.7.8/cast.cgi?type="text/plain"&url="https://1.2.3.4/a.txt"` to do the type casting.

The second thing is to improve it and have these parameters:

```
https://5.6.7.8/view.cgi?
  lang="c"
  adjust-indent="k&r"
  colour="colour_template_1"
  typeface="typeface_template_2"
  url="https://1.2.3.4/2.c"`
```

or avoid inventing the wheel and [embbed any editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript-based_source_code_editors) .

I know all above mentioned features can be implemented by myself within the time of a cup of tea, but getting it hosted is a major problem. So I am looking for an existing solution with a (shorter/better) sensible URL scheme, which is free on the internet.